# While loop with condition consisting of variable amount of if statements in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, while-loop

I'm trying to do the following. Say I have a vector, E, of length N. What I want to do is create a while loop of the form

```
while E(1) < A || E(2) < A || ..... || E(N) < A
do stuff
end
```

where A is some input value, say 0.5.

However, I'd like this to work for any N (probably up to like, 50), so I can't just type out every single condition. I know that this is probably computationally expensive, but in principle this shouldn't matter for my purposes.

The problem is, I have no idea how to do this. Perhaps I can use some sort of for loop to create a string that is equal to the condition that I want? I'm not familiar enough with this part of MATLAB to know if that is possible, but I'm assuming this is the direction I should be thinking of.

Comment: It would be good if you posted some sample data and some sample conditions (i.e. create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). There might be another way of doing it that you haven't thought of...

Comment: Alright, I'll try and think of a suitable one. The problem is really that I have two vectors, E1 and E2. What I want to do in the end is make a function that adjusts E1 to become more like E2, for every element. There's quite some conditions that have to be satisfied though, so it would be a different question entirely. But in essence I just want my loop to terminate once every element E1(j) is at least A*E2(j).

Comment: You should have put that info into your question...

Comment: Yes, I suppose so, but I didn't want to have someone solve the entire problem for me without at least trying for a while myself. The last line is basically what I wrote, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compact the test as:

```
while any(E<A)
```

Basically, it compute the mask of all values of `E` less than `A`, and the function `any` returns true if at least one element is true.

Comment: Well, that's amazing.

Comment: @user129412 Yeah, it's called vectorization :). It's the very core of Matlab. Once you get it, you'll love it.